# Apply rewrite rule to nginx vhost from apache vhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

I'm making some tests with nginx.

He works fine, but i'm unable to apply some rewrite rules from apache and nginx doc is not really easy.

Goal : everything has to be rewrited on the /index.php file instead of extra and adminer.

If i browse to http://server/extra/someThing, it's OK, the controller.php file is called.

But for /adminer, i just want to prevent /adminer to be rewrited by the last rule.

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/extra /extra/controller.php break;
    #rewrite ^/adminer - break;
    rewrite ^/ /index.php break;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use separate location blocks to partition your rewrite logic. For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
location /extra {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /extra/controller.php;
}
location /adminer {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

Comment: Thanks but the "location /" doesnt works and php files are not executed, i need to change it to "location ~", and after this, "location /extra" and "location /adminer" use the /index.php file. Without the ~ nothing works.

Comment: Finally it's done, probably not the best way but it works :

    location /adminer {
  try_files $uri =404;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
 return 403;
}
location ~ {
  rewrite ^/extra /extra/controller.php break;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  include fastcgi_params;
}

Thanks for help